# How to make a generic lambda that compares any Number of identical type

Tags: java, generics, lambda, static, numbers

I have a need to replace a comparison operator at runtime, where two Numbers would be compared GreaterThanOrEquals, LessThanOrEquals, Equals, etc. but ideally I don't replicate my code for Integers, Doubles, Longs, Shorts, Floats and Bytes. Part of my requirements is keeping the operation in lambdas as much as possible for performance.

Note: Both values will always be the same type. I have no intention of doing mixed-type comparisons.

Here is a rough of my code. I tried to just parameterize the last static method with Java.lang.Number, but >= won't work on Number:

```
public class Expression {
    public Param p1;
    public Operator o;
    public Param p2;

    public Object eval() {
        return o.eval(p1.getValue(),p2.getValue());
    }
}


public interface Operator<T>{
    Object eval(T p1,T p2);
}


public interface GreaterOrEqual extends Operator<Number>{
    static Operator<Integer> Integers() {
        return (v1, v2) -> v1 >= v2;
    }

    static Operator<Double> Doubles() {
        return (v1, v2) -> v1 >= v2;
    }

    static Operator<Long> Longs() {
        return (v1, v2) -> v1 >= v2;
    }

    static Operator<Number> generic() {
        // this one won't compile as ">= can't be applied to Java.lang.Number"
        return (v1, v2) -> v1 >= v2;
    }

}
```

Edit: This code duplication also means my GUI code will need to use a `if (Param.value instanceof Integer) Expression.setOperator(GreaterOrEqual.Integers);` which is even more code duplication.

Comment: You can do `v1.doubleValue() >= v2.doubleValue()`

Comment: Wouldn't this be slow performance? Converting every value to a double? One of the requirements is high performance... possibly running over and over in the microseconds... depending on current load.

Comment: What is the intention of `Operator`? What is the idea behind returning `Object` from `eval`?

Comment: Operator is to be an interface, and it’s children give its lambda functionality, like a strategy pattern. Either a GUI or a text parser would build the Expression object. Returning Object because depending on the operation, it might need to be Boolean, or Integer/Double (such as a Multiplication operator).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing you have to understand that you are getting no benefit from writing `Operator<Integer>`. Java uses auto-boxing to convert `int` to the `Integer` wrapper object. Then in your code (`(v1, v2) -> v1 >= v2`) the `Integer` object is converted back into an `int`.

A more universal solution would use the `Comparable` interface.  `Number` doesn't implement the interface, but all the important Number implementations like `Double` support it.

```
Operator<Comparable<?>> gt = (v1, v2) -> v1.compareTo(v2) > 0;
Operator<Comparable<?>> ge = (v1, v2) -> v1.compareTo(v2) >= 0;
Operator<Comparable<?>> ge = (v1, v2) -> v1.compareTo(v2) = 0;
Operator<Comparable<?>> le = (v1, v2) -> v1.compareTo(v2) <= 0;
Operator<Comparable<?>> lt = (v1, v2) -> v1.compareTo(v2) < 0;
```

`compareTo` returns 1 if the parameter is smaller, 0 if it's the same size and -1 of it is bigger.

Comment: Oh this is good to know on Autoboxing. I was using that to force both values to be of same type… but I can force it other ways. So Comparable would not work on Integer, but would work on Double, Long, Float? Do you think I should convert to Int to Double for the comparison (like @QBrute mentioned)?

Comment: It works on all the wrapper classes including `Integer`. `int` and `Integer` is not the same. One is an object the other a primitive type.

Answer (score 0):

### Usage of Comparable Interface

```java
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> int compare(T x, T y) {
    return x != null ? x.compareTo(y) : -y.compareTo(x);
}
```

**Possible Outcomes**

- `-1`, when `x` is less than `y`
- `0`, when `x` is equal to `y`
- `1`, when `x` is greater than `y`

### Possible Usage

`compare(x, y) < 0` - `x` is less than `y`
`compare(x, y) <= 0` - `x` is less than or equal `y`
`compare(x, y) == 0` - `x` equals `y`
`compare(x, y) >= 0` - `x` is greater than or equal `y`
`compare(x, y) > 0` - `x` is greater than `y`

---

If there is a mistake or an issue, please notify me!